# how to load another nib file?

Tags: iphone

how to load another nib file from viewbased application.

I added button in root nib file.... on clicking button i need to load another nib file.

Comment: @ ranjeet sajwan ...can you give tell me detailed way...   Thanks in advance

Comment: i add new class UIViewController Subclass...called abcd..... new i created abcd nib for that uiviewcontroller..... I added a new button when button click my abcd nib file need to load : I created project of ViewBased Application

Comment: ControllerMusic *music = [[ControllerMusic alloc] initWithNibName:@"BusinessUser" bundle:nil];
 [self.view addSubview:music.view];
 [music release]; I used this in -(IBAction)PlaylistButtonPressed:(id)sender

Answer (score 0):

In app delegate use this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

and

In controller class use:

```
    -(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender{

 SecondViewController *_secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:_secondView animated:YES];

    }
```

It will works fine..... enjoy

Thanks people.